# Does AWS Cognito for iOS allow offline sign in?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-ios

I'm trying to figure out if AWS Cognito for iOS allows users to sign in while offline. It would be handy but I haven't been able to find anything to show that this is or is not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by offline signin?  If the purpose of the signin is to get access to AWS then what do you hope to accomplish?If what you want are "Id" and some information that you sync while online, then that might be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito user pools does not support offline sign in on any SDK at this time.